# How to override a JS file in lib folder in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs, tinymce

I want to override a JS file which lives in following folder

```
MAGENTO_ROOT\lib\web\tiny_mce\plugins\advimage\js\image.js
```

I want to override this file from my custom admin theme or by a module.

Any code snippet or how-to will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you want to override in custom front or admin theme?

Comment: I want to override it in adminhtml

Answer (score 9):

You should copy this file to your theme by following path:

`MAGENTO_ROOT\app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\web\tiny_mce\plugins\advimage\js\image.js`

*replace 'Magento\luma' by your own theme

And then make necessary changes into the file. Magento will use this file automatically instead file from the lib folder.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I want to override it in adminhtml.

Answer (score 0):

In the Module Magento2-base

> html/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/image.htm:10

You have seen the script include that **js/image.js**

How to override this **htm** file read more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430036/override-html-file-in-custom-module-magento2

Answer (score 0):

You can mixin the lib file like so:

the file: PROJECT_ROOT/lib/web/mage/**menu.js**

> VENDOR/THEME/**require-config.js**

```
var config = { 
     "config": {
        "mixins": {
           "mage/menu": {
               "js/mage/menu-mixin": true
           }
        }
     }
}
```

> VENDOR/THEME/web/js/mage/**menu-mixin.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
   'use strict';

   var menuMixin = {
       // overriden method 
       toggle: function () {
           this.sayHello();
           this._super();
       },
       // new method
       sayHello: function() {
          alert('Hello!')
       }
   };

   return function (targetWidget) {
       // Example how to extend a widget by mixin object
       $.widget('mage.menu', targetWidget.menu, menuMixin);
       return $.mage.menu;
   };
});
```

It is well documeted here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

The tricky part is with 'lib' folder, but it is described above.